# Proof check: Show that $B_{t} \sim N(0,t)$ is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, brownian-motion, expected-value

Let $B_{t} \sim N(0,t)$, and show that $E[\lvert B_{t}\rvert ] < \infty$

My idea:

$E[\lvert B_{t}\rvert ]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lvert y\rvert e^{-\frac{y^2}{2t}}dy$

and then by symmetry of the probability density function, we have

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lvert y\rvert e^{-\frac{y^2}{2t}}dy=2\int_{0}^{\infty}ye^{-\frac{y^2}{2t}}dy$

Now note that $\exp(y)\geq y$ on $\mathbb R$. So we obtain the bound

$\int_{0}^{\infty}ye^{-\frac{y^2}{2t}}dy\leq \int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(y-\frac{y^2}{2t})dy$

By completing the square:
$y -\frac{y^{2}}{2t}=-\frac{(y^2-2ty+t^2-t^2)}{2t}=-\frac{(y-t)^2-t^2}{2t}$
So:

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(y-\frac{y^2}{2t})=\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-\left(\frac{(y-t)^2-t^2}{2t}\right))dy=\exp(\frac{t}{2})\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-\left(\frac{y-t}{\sqrt{2t}}\right)^{2})dy$

And we set $z = \frac{y-t}{\sqrt{2t}}$ to deliver

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(\left(\frac{y-t}{\sqrt{2t}}\right)^{2})dy\leq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-z^{2})dz = \sqrt{\pi}$

Does this suffice?

Comment: It suffices but why not just use the fact that $E|B_t| \leq \sqrt {EB_t^{2}}=\sqrt t$?

Comment: Is $B_t$ a Brownian motion? If yes, then it suffices to use the "continuity with probability 1" property of Brownian motion to prove this.

Comment: @TheGrandDuke What do you mean? How does continuity help? Since $B_t$ is Gaussian, we have $\sup_{\omega} |B_t(\omega)|=\infty$ for each $t>0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I got confused. Are you trying to prove that $B_t$ is integrable (what the title says)? Or that $\mathbb{E}|B_t|<\infty$?

Comment: The definition of integrability is that $B_{t}$ is in $L^{1}$ and that is what I was trying to prove?

Comment: The easier way can be to just evaluate that $\int_0^\infty y \exp(-\frac{y^2}{2t}) dy$ by setting $z=y^2$, so $dz = 2ydy$

Comment: Look up folded normal distribution

Answer (score 1):

You can either use Jensen inequality as stated in the comment by user **Kavi Rama Murthy** or find it directly.

First for each, $B_t$ has the same distribution as $\sigma B_1 =\sqrt t B_1$ and $B_1$ is standard normal random variable. Now you calculate

$$\mathbb E|\sigma B_1|=\mathbb E \sigma B_1 -2 \sigma\mathbb E(  B_1 : B_1\leq 0)$$
And the last integral is simply
$$\int_{-\infty}^0 x\phi(x)  dx=-\int_0^\infty x\phi(x) dx=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{-u}du=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$
which gives
$$\mathbb E |B_t|=-2\sigma \cdot-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}=\sqrt{\frac{2t}{\pi}}$$